# How can I make this regular expression work?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match sets of data from a PDF document. Because this PDF was generated from OCR and PDF in general don't have data arranged in a way a program can fetch easily, the data I receive looks, for instance, like this:

> 12/26 CORRECTION Card Ending in 1111 427.85 3,611.31 Some avenue name12/26 OFF-US ATM WITHDRAWAL 803.00 2,808.31 OAKBROOK SQUARE OFFICE PALM BCH GDNSFLUS 12/26 ATM WITHDRAWAL 419.46 2,388.85 Some avenue name 12/26 SERVICE CHARGES 8.39 2,380.46 Foreign Transaction Fee 12/29 OFF-US ATM WITHDRAWAL 802.50 1,577.96 THE BREAKERS PALM BCH PALM BEACH FLUS 12/30 ATM WITHDRAWAL 600.00 977.96 11111 US HWY 1, PALM BEACH, FL 12/31 ACH DEBIT 207.94 770.02 PAYBYPHONE-PYMT PHONE PYMT 1111 Dec 31 12/31 ACH DEBIT 138.00 632.02 BK OF AM CRD ACH PAYBYPHONE 01111111 Dec 31

I'm trying to extract from there a date, a header, two numeric values, followed by a comment that may or may not exist, that are hopefully separated by spaces, that may or may not be there. So I went this far with my regular expression:

```
/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})\s*(.+?)\s*([\d,]+\.\d\d)\s*([\d,]+\.\d\d-?)\s*(.*?)/g
```

And this is the live example: https://regex101.com/r/yU2bN7/1

The problem is, it matches all it should, except the comment. The very last lazy `(.*?)` matches nothing, and if I make it greedy, it will match the other data sets as if they were part of the first match. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a positive lookahead for end-of-string or start-of-next-pattern:

```
(?=$|\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})
```

Comment: I was about to post the same answer. Here's a demo: https://regex101.com/r/yU2bN7/2